# How to Update DataTable in C# without For Each Loop?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable, datarow

I'm trying to run loop for each row in my data table but its giving me error as I can't modify a collection in for each loop ... what else can i do to update table?

I am trying to remove duplicate entries w.r.t single column that is **appliance name** and if such selection is made based on duplicate appliance name then simply update the old **quantity**.

Here is the code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Appliance Name", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Quantity", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("Day Time(Hrs)", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("Backup Time(Hrs)", typeof(int));
        // dt.Rows.Add("Sana", 5, 4, 3);
        Session["MyDataTable"] = dt;
    }
}

protected void BtnAddNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dtab = (DataTable)Session["MyDataTable"];

    if (dtab.Rows.Count != 0)
    {
        foreach (DataRow r in dtab.Rows)
        {
            if (Convert.ToString(r["Appliance Name"]) == DDLAppName.Text)
            {
                int temp = Convert.ToInt32(r["Quantity"]);
                r["Quantity"] = Convert.ToInt32(QtyTB.Text) + temp;
            }
            else
            {
                dtab.Rows.Add(DDLAppName.SelectedValue, Convert.ToInt32(QtyTB.Text), Convert.ToInt32(DayTymTB.Text), Convert.ToInt32(BackUpTymTB.Text));
            }
        }
    }
    else if (dtab.Rows.Count == 0)
    {
        dtab.Rows.Add(DDLAppName.SelectedValue, Convert.ToInt32(QtyTB.Text), Convert.ToInt32(DayTymTB.Text), Convert.ToInt32(BackUpTymTB.Text));
    }

    //dtab = dtab.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "Appliance Name", "Quantity", "Day Time(Hrs)", "Backup Time(Hrs)");
    AllItems.DataSource = dtab;
    AllItems.DataBind();
    AllItems.Visible = true;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Simply try using `for` loop instead of `foreach` like this:

```
for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < dtab.Rows.Count; rowIndex++)
{
    DataRow r = dtab.Rows[rowIndex];
    if (Convert.ToString(r["Appliance Name"]) == DDLAppName.Text)
    {
      int temp = Convert.ToInt32(r["Quantity"]);
      r["Quantity"] = Convert.ToInt32(QtyTB.Text) + temp;
    }
    else
    {
      dtab.Rows.Add(DDLAppName.SelectedValue, Convert.ToInt32(QtyTB.Text), Convert.ToInt32(DayTymTB.Text), Convert.ToInt32(BackUpTymTB.Text));
    }
}
```

**EDIT 1:** 
The foreach statement is used to iterate through the collection to get the information that you want, but can not be used to add or remove items from the source collection to avoid unpredictable side effects. If you need to add or remove items from the source collection, use a for loop. (From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx))

**Edit 2**
If you wanna add rows in your `foreach` loop, do as follows:

```
    DataRow[] dataRows = new DataRow[dt.Rows.Count];
    dt.Rows.CopyTo(dataRows, 0);
    foreach (DataRow r in dataRows)
    {
              ...
    }
```

Comment: what is 'i' here??  dtab.Rows[i]; ??

Comment: oh oh sorry, it should be rowIndex, I'll edit the post.

Comment: What is the advantage of using for loop instead of foreach ..?

Comment: As you saw in the exception message, the original collection can't be changed in a `foreach` loop, so you should use `for` loop instead and get the row by it's index.

Comment: But its still giving duplicate enteries :/

Comment: Adding an entry again and again due to for loop .. and additional entries being increased as number of table rows are being increased

Comment: OK I'll take a look at you logic, I just tried to answer your question about how to update datatable without a `foreach` loop :)

Comment: If i am adding break in both if and else brackets then also its not working ... :/

Comment: That's because of the else part, actually that was the main problem, your'e trying to add rows in the loop, which you don't have to.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46493/discussion-between-sana-91-and-arin-ghazarian)

Comment: @pravprab: if you have a question, please post that. this is an unnecessary comment.